# Excel Oracle query takes long to run

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, vba

I connect to an oracle database with an ADODB connection in Excel. When i run the query in SQL developer, it run about 8 secs (this is for the full result of 45 000 records). When i run the same quakes very in Excel vba it takes very long, about 20 minutes. Why would it take so long in Excel?

Here is an example of my code,

```
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set con = New ADODB.Connection

con.CursorLocation = adUseClient
con.Open "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)" & _
                       "(HOST=JASONPC)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=jasonpc)));User Id=jason;Password=jason;DeferUpdChk=true"


rs.CursorType = ADODB.adOpenStatic
rs.LockType = adLockOptimistic
rs.Open sql, con

Set rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing
con.Close
Set con = Nothing
```

Comment: what is the query? do you attempt to load results?

Comment: Try changing the locktype to adLockReadonly

Answer (score 0):

If you execute for full 45K records it will slow your execution or hangs Excel. So run it from 5K query

First 10k then next 10k and so on Using row num in the query...

So you need to modify your based on that Query